# DataGridView Winforms Populate ComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I am making one software where the user will create an invoice using datagridview.
I have some textbox cells and some combobox cells.
There are some things I want to do:

1. I want to fill the combobox cells
   from database table. I tried this:

   `DataTable tblItems = UtilityClass.GetDataTable("SELECT ItemName,ItemID FROM Items");
     DataGridViewComboBoxColumn itemCol=DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridViewNewBill.Columns["ColItem"];
     itemCol.DataSource = tblItems;
     itemCol.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
     itemCol.ValueMember = "ItemID";`

   But, after an item is selected, and
   when the focus is moved to a
   different cell, the item selected in
   the combobox (or text of textbox)
   cell disappears.
   **EDIT**: It seems as
   if selecting an item in the combobox
   causes all the combobox cells to get
   that value because they have the
   same datasource ! But even if it's
   the case, why the combox/textbox
   cell loses it's value after focus is
   moved to a different cell.

Comment: Ask *one* question only.

Comment: changed from multi question to single question.

Comment: Just a suggestion: If you have time and are still at the beginning of your project: WPF and the Entity Framework 4 would save you quite some trouble. I don't regret looking into it myself.

Comment: Are you handling any events for the grid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am now quite sure that when we use the same data source for 2 or more comboboxes, changing the value for one causes the others to change also.

What I did was disable adding new rows and

1. In the form load added one row,
   setting the datasource of that
   particular combobox cell(not
   column).
2. When the user moves to the last cell
   and presses enter key, I create
   another row and do the same as
   above.

In this way each cell has a different data source, although I have to do some more work but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Are you handling any specific events which is erasing the data.

Selecting a value causes it to be selected for other cells because the Grid uses a common *ComboBox* across all cells of the combobox column which is the *EditingControl* for enabling selection of the values of the column.

You can control the behviour by handling the **EditingControlShowing** event

Try setting this mode

```
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```